# iPhone Simulator does not see items in iCloud

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I have documents uploaded into iCloud. Using the iPhone Simulator (iOS 15.2), I go to Files -> Browse -> iCloud, but the documents do not show up here.

I am logged into the iPhone Simulator with the same AppleID that is used with the iCloud account.

What could be the problem here? Could it be a setting with the simulator?